# Mapping values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to map values in a dictionary to keys present in another dictionary,

```
dict1 = {'CityA':'abc','CityB':'c-abc','CityC':'xyz'}

dict2 = {'abc':['abc','ABC','c-abc'],
         'xyz':['xyz']}
```

The values in dictionary `dict1` should be mapped to keys in `dict2` if the value in `dict1` occurs in value of `dict2`

Expected output:

```
dict = {'CityA':'abc','CityB':'abc','CityC':'xyz'}
```

I'm not sure what could be the best way to do this.

I'm trying the following

```
for v in dict1.values():
    if v in dict2.values(): # dict2.values() is a list containing list
```

Is it a good way to loop through the items(lists) of the list?

Or is there any inbuilt function that can loop through all items in the list
containing list?

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
dict1 =`{'CityA':['abc','xyz'],'CityB':'c-abc','CityC':['ABC','xyz']}
```

Expected Output:

```
dict =`{'CityA':['abc','xyz'],'CityB':'abc','CityC':['abc','xyz']}
```

Test case: If there is no mapping for a string in dict2, the string should be retained in new_d

```
dict1 = {'CityA': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'CityB': 'c-abc', 'CityC': ['ABC', 'xyz', 'ith']}
```

Expected output:

```
{'CityA': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'CityB': 'abc', 'CityC': ['abc', 'xyz', 'ith']}
```

Output obtained:

```
{'CityA': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'CityB': 'abc', 'CityC': ['abc', 'xyz']}
```

Comment: You might want to swap the values and keys in `dict2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested comprehension:

```
dict1 = {'CityA':'abc','CityB':'c-abc','CityC':'xyz'}
dict2 = {'abc':['abc','ABC','c-abc'], 'xyz':['xyz']}
new_d = {a:[c for c, d in dict2.items() if b in d][0] for a, b in dict1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'CityA': 'abc', 'CityB': 'abc', 'CityC': 'xyz'}
```

In case there is no corresponding value for a given key in `dict2`, you can use a `lambda` to retain the original value:

```
dict1 = {'CityA': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'CityB': 'c-abc', 'CityC': ['ABC', 'xyz']}
dict2 = {'abc':['abc','ABC','c-abc'], 'xyz':['xyz']}
new_d = {a:(lambda x:b if not x else x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x)([c for c, d in dict2.items() 
     if (b in d if not isinstance(b, list) else any(j in d for j in b))]) for a, b in dict1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'CityA': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'CityB': 'abc', 'CityC': ['abc', 'xyz']}
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I'm sorry my dict1 is `{'CityA':['abc','xyz'],'CityB':'c-abc','CityC':['ABC','xyz']}`

Comment: @Natasha What is your new desired output?

Comment: @Natasha No problem. Please use the select solution I posted to achieve your new desired final output.

Comment: Thanks a lot.There is a mismatch in the output of `CityC`. Expexted: 'CityC': ['abc', 'xyz']

Comment: I tried a test case for which there is no mapping for a string in dict1. `dict1 = {'CityA': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'CityB': 'c-abc', 'CityC': ['ABC', 'xyz', 'ith']}` Please check the update of test case in my original post